# Automatically connect to ms excel and check for unread emails using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am doing a project based on excel-vba.

There are 2 users. User A and User B

User A has an excel workbook with a table. User B will be emailing a
 document regularly,to user A's outlook account.

My requirement is by using a macro to give 2 options to user A.

option 1: manually check if there is unread email from a particular
 user.

This is done by:

Opening outlook from within the excel workbook and then User A can manualy search through the outlook account.

I have successfully done this using the following code.

```
    Sub Open_Outlook()

    ' This Macro Opens Microsoft Outlook
    ' Runs an executable program

    Shell ("OUTLOOK")

    End Sub
```

option 2: Automatically check if there is unread email from a particular user.

This is done by:

1. Create a Connection to Outlook.
2. Checking if there is any unread email.

Sub ExtractFirstUnreadEmailDetails()

```
Dim oOutlook As Object
Dim oOlns As Object
Dim oOlInb As Object


'~~> Get Outlook instance
Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set oOlns = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'~~> Check if there are any actual unread emails
If oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True").Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "NO Unread Email In Inbox"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

End Sub

**I am getting an error when i run the code for the second option.**

**Run time error 429: Active X component cant create object.**

**What does this mean?**

**How do i change the code to get rid of the error and to run it succesfully?**

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help.
Its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

olFolderInbox is a Outlook only constant Either define it as a constant in VBA like this:

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6
```

Or simply replace it with 6 in the Set oOlInb line

Comment: Thank you very much
It work worked.

Why do i have to define olFolderInbox as a constant?

Comment: Because it is a constant within Outlook but not Excel, adding the reference to Outlook doesn't add it's constants. If this code were in Outlook VBA (which would negate most of it so is a moot point but for the purpose of this let's just go with it) you would not need to Constant it as it is done at the App level